# shell script use ssh remote run command whit nohup in the background,but this ssh process can not be close. but I use the screen is all perfect

Tags: bash, shell, ssh

I use shell script run ssh command to remote excute cammand whit nohup in the background,but ssh connect can not quit, shell script as well can not quit. why is that, this is my want to know.

when i use screen command is perfect.

I find out when i excute command with nohup ,the command parent process ID is ssh connection carete of bash process ID.when I kill ssh connection the commadn parent process ID is 1 (init).

when i use screen,the command parent process ID is screen carete of bash process ID.screen parent process ID is 1.

Sorry for my poor English

Comment: What is the ssh command you run?

Comment: like this:root@localhost "nohup  sh /tmp/cmd.sh &"， in the /tmp/cmd.sh is a while loop, while true;do :;done. will not quit.

Comment: add a '-n' flag to your ssh command. man ssh for more details.

Comment: I try to everything ,found the reason is in `nohup` command is never to quit. Use the `screen` is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `ssh` is not allowed to exit if one of your applications is still connected to it for terminal input/output.

You can try redirecting your background process' input:

```
nohup sh /tmp/cmd.sh </dev/null &
```

And perhaps the output as well:

```
nohup sh /tmp/cmd.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

`&>/dev/null` can be a shortcut but may not always work depending on the shell.

**Warning:** Leaving a process running on infinite loop is a very bad thing and could be dangerous i.e. it could burn the system.

At least you should modify your loop with `sleep`'s so it would be less heavy and so you could also trace it easily later:

```
while true; do sleep 10; done
```

Comment: `nohup sh /tmp/cmd.sh </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & ` can worked.thanks. but i want to know why. Can help to explain

Comment: Use the `screen` run this program is better than `nohup`.

Comment: actually. In `nohup` commad is can be another command,As long as this command does not exit. The ssh connection will not exit.

Comment: @Txxk As I hypothesized it's possible that the virtual terminal summoned by ssh on the remote end would not exit as long an application is still accessing the virtual stdin/stdout/stderr (which are actually pipes) created by it. Even if an application is on the background, it can still be able to accesses the stdout/stderr so disconnecting the application from it by redirection to null or another device or file would allow the terminal to exit.